# Laravel validate incoming ajax using request

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a view like this:

// snippet of view

```
<td><input class="form-field" type="text" id="entity" name="name" data="{{$entity->id}}" value="{{$entity->name}}" onkeyup="validation(this.value);" onblur="updateEntity(this.value,this.name,this.id,{{$entity->id}})"></td>

<td><input class="form-field" type="text" id="entity" name="type" value="{{$entity->type}}" onkeyup="validation(this.value);" onblur="updateEntity(this.value,this.name,this.id,{{$entity->id}})"></td>
```

Which has an ajax:

```
function updateEntity(value, name, data, id) {
  $.ajax({
        url: '/entityadmin/' + value + '/' + name + '/' + data + '/' + id,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(save) {
          $('.messages').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Type Updated!<div>');
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
                $(".alert").slideUp(500);
              });  
            }, 4000); 
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $('.messages').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">Error, please try again!<div>');
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
                $(".alert").slideUp(500);
              });  
            }, 4000); 
        },
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function entityUpdate($value, $name, $data, $id, EntityRequestUpdate $request) {

        $request->$name = $value; //like this?
        if($data == "entity") {
            $save = Entity::find($id);
        }else{
            $save = User::find($id);
        }
        $save->$name = $value;
        $save->save();
        return response()->json(['results' => $save]);       
    }
```

and request:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'startdate' => 'required|date',
            'endate' => 'nullable|date',
            'startime' => 'required|time',
            'endtime' => 'required|time',
            'title' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'frequency' => 'required',
            'interval' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'monthday' => 'nullable|numeric|min:1|max:3',
            'weekday' => 'nullable|alpha|max:3',
            'month' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'until' => 'nullable|date',
            'tags' => 'nullable',
            'img' => 'nullable|file|image',
        ];
    }
```

The thing is it only has to validate one field because one field is being changed each time, how can I use this validation to validate the incoming variable and return errors to ajax with the message on the error if there is any?

Answer (score 0):

You can [manually create a validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators) to validate this one field like so:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    [ 'name' => $value ], 
    collect($this->rules())->only([$name])->all()
);
```

This validator will take the `name` validator from the defined rules and check that against the first array of values.

Comment: how is it going to know the validation rule for that specific field? because the validation might be needed for name or email or anything else depending on what is actually being edited

Comment: I updated the question so the validator uses the dynamic `$name`.